# Https client for WebGL build in Unity3d

Tags: c#, sockets, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I need https client for WebGL build.

[WWW](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html) is horrible. First of all, it doesn't support keep-alive connections, plus it has problems with https.

[UnityWebRequest](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.html) doesn't support keep-alive.

There is [plugin](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/38367) for WebSockets by Unity team, but it was last updated year ago.

For other platforms I have wrote custom solution based on raw sockets (C# `TcpClient`), but `UnityEngine.Network` namespace [isn't supported in WebGL build](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-networking.html).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like [UnityWebRequest](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.html) is fine now. In Unity 5.3 it was in experimental namespace and it literally haven't worked.

In Untiy 5.4 this class was moved to `UnityEngine.Networking` and seems stable. And, surprisingly, it has support for keep-alive connection. So, for WebGL build I can use it (at least with Unity >= 5.4).

**Note:** for WebGL build your server should set [CORS headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS). Also, your server should support OPTIONS requests.

Comment: unity has stated that it does not support keep-alive:  https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/dictionary-support-or-workaround-for-jsonutility-test-case-included.379415/ - if you have figured out how to make keep-alive work please update your answer (i wasted time trying updating to UnityWebRequest only to find it keep-alive was not working)

Comment: @JoeBooth Duno why minus... I don't see any mentions about `keep-alive` in that discussion. I'm using it like `UnityWebRequest.Post(url, data)` and `keep-alive` works at least on Android and StandAlone platforms.